# how to restructure Xmls with Linq XDocument?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to restructure loads of xmls. the prefer way of doing is Linq with XDocument .. but I am welcome to any suggesting you may have. Thanks a lot.

I scratched a picture .. I hope it is enough to explain what I wanna do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
var original = XDocument.Load(...);
var replacement = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root",
        original.Descendants("Song")
                .GroupBy(x => (string) x.Attribute("artist"))
                .Select((songsForArtist, index) => new XElement("artist",
                    new XAttribute("id", index + 1),
                    new XAttribute("name", songsForArtist.Key),
                    songsForArtist)));
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was trying to do Jon .. Thanks a million .. :D

Comment: Hi Jon , ... I am here requesting a bit of help from you .. I am really in need of it .. I tried to do it myself for a week but couldn't do it .. Thanks for your help last time, I need a change on it .. instead of <Song title=" ... " artist=" ... " album=" .. "> can i have <Song title=".. " artistID="1" album=" .. " ..... artistID in Song would reflect  <artist ID="">  in <artist> Thanks so much Jon, I hope you would see my comment and would help me with it.

Comment: @LaurenceNyein: It would be far clearer if you'd ask this as a separate question, including what you've tried, what you're trying to achieve etc.

Comment: Thanks John .. I did ask a new post and someone just answered it .. and it worked .. nice day!

Comment: This is the post .. if you wanna check .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494902/need-help-converting-datatable-to-xml-vb-net/10497055#comment13571398_10497055